# Eclipse: cannot run a servlet like on Netbean: HTTP Status 404

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets, netbeans, http-status-code-404

I have a simple Servlet and run both form Netbean and Eclipse.

First,I run in Netbean steps by steps:

1) right click project: Build

2) right click project: Deploy

3) right click project: Run --> Successfully run.

But, in Eclipse, here is steps by steps:

1) Build by Control+B

2) right click on project: run as>Run on server

--->`HTTP Status 404` error !!!

Both link in browser when I run from eclipse or netbean have same: for example,`http://localhost:8084/HelloServlet/.`

So, It means maybe Eclipse doesn't deploy my apps yet.

Please teach me how to run Servlet in Eclipse.

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you mapped your welcome file in web.xml?

Comment: Yes. And both project has same web.xml

Comment: What is happening here is that the server is not able to find any mappings corresponding to the path `HelloServlet/`. Can you post you web.xml here?

Comment: is your app deployed as  "HelloServlet" ? By Default, it searches for <wel-come> list files from web.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the right server connectors installed? Open the "Servers" view by clicking: Window -> Show View -> Servers (or maybe -> others... -> Servers). If your server (with the correct version) is not listed: click right mouse in Servers view -> New -> Server -> choose the right connector and install it. Then drag your project to the newly created server or choose "Add and remove" by right clicking the servers name.